# How to preserve decimal precision when exporting to a csv and opened with excel

Tags: c#, excel, csv, decimal, precision

I have exported the values to a csv file in c#.

The csv file has all 5 decimal places present for each value, yet when opened with excel, the decimal places are reduced to two for each one.

Is there a way of programatically ensuring that the decimal places are kept when the csv is opened in excel?

```
var nFI = new NumberFormatInfo();

nFI.NumberDecimalDigits = precision;
line += (CsvEscape(((decimal)dr[colName]).ToString("N", nFI)) + ",");
```

This is how the decimals are exported to the csv.

Comment: Excel is just plain evil when it comes to csv files. We had a tool that exported gtin numbers (13 digits) into csv. When opened in excel it automatically changes their representation to scientific, replacing many digits with zero. Never hit save, when viewing csv in excel.

Comment: Solved! See below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When outputting to a csv file, to preserve the decimal places, wrap the value in double quotes and prefix a '=' sign. (Excuse the code, its still in prototype form)

```
line += ("=" + '"' (((decimal)dr[colName]).ToString("N",nFI).Replace(",",""))+ '"' + ",");
```

This outputs as ="63000.00000",

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a format provider (`NumberFormatInfo`) for any other purpose? If you omit the formatting parameters in `ToString()` it should output as-is.

Comment: That's what i tried to start with, but because 4 of 5 decimal places were 0, it got rid of them. Client requirements state that they need to zeros there.

Comment: Try using `ToString("0.000000");` -- This will use zeros for any digit not there. So "0" becomes 0.000000 and 1.1 becomes 1.100000. 0.5 becomes 0.500000, etc.

This page has a reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: This didn't seem to work, no decimal places unless the place was more than 0.

Comment: If the values are correct when viewing it in Notepad, or similar, then the issue is more in how Excel formats numbers, as CSharpie said above.